# How do I find out what is causing my state to change?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am rendering a list of files containing a name and size. This list of files are managed by a state in a parent component. Deeper down my component tree where the files are actually rendered, I'm using the [Material-UI's Slide Transition component](https://material-ui.com/components/transitions/) so that on the first render, the files "slide" into the container. I also passed down a handleDelete callback function so that when the user clicks on the file, it gets removed from the state. Here is some of my code:

```
// Sample file list contained in parent component:

function File({ file, handleDelete }) {
  const [rendered, setRendered] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!rendered) {
      console.log(file.name);
      handleDelete(file.name);
    }
  }, [rendered]);

  return (
    <Slide direction="left" in={rendered} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>
      <div className={styles.File} onClick={() => setRendered(false)}>
        <p>{file.name}</p>
        <p>{file.size.toFixed(2)} MB</p>
      </div>
    </Slide>
  );
}

function FileList({ files, handleDelete }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {files.map((file, i) => (
        <File key={i} file={file} handleDelete={handleDelete} />
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

and then I have the handleDelete callback function in the parent component:

```
  const handleDelete = (fileName) => {
    var newFiles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (files[i].name != fileName) {
        newFiles.push(files[i]);
      }
    }
    handleSetFiles(newFiles);
  };
```

and handleSetFules is simply:

```
  const handleSetFiles = (newFiles) => {
    setFiles(newFiles);
  };
```

The *rendered* state in the *File* component governs whether each file should slide in and be displayed if true or slide out if false. When I add my files to the list, everything renders as expected. When I click the file, I want to set the *rendered* state to false which would slide out the file and trigger the useEffect hook which would then delete the file from the state. Lets say the FileList component renders each File according to the following passed in prop:

```
const files = [
  {name: "file1", size: "1MB"},
  {name: "file2", size: "1MB"},
  {name: "file3", size: "1MB"},
  {name: "file4", size: "1MB"},
  {name: "file5", size: "1MB"},
];
```

If I click *file1*, what happens is the *rendered* state for *file1* gets set to false and triggers the useEffect and gets removed from the list and is no longer displayed. Exactly as expected. HOWEVER, for some reason, the file below i.e. *file2* also gets its *rendered* state set to false and is not displayed BUT it doesn't trigger the useEffect hook nor does it call *handleDelete*. When I use the Chrome DevTools, I see the *File* component for *file1* is removed but *file2* is still listed with its *rendered* state as false. The rest of the *File* components are displayed and they all still have their *rendered* state as true. I've been debugging this for hours and I cannot figure out what is causing my state to change. What's weird is if I remove the useEffect and click *file1*, *file2*'s state does not change. Any help on whats going on? I tried looking into the documents for Material-UI Slide but couldn't find anywhere where it would change the state like that...

Answer (score 0):

So, I believe the root of your problem is that the Slide operates by hiding and showing a component, not by removing it from the DOM. So, you should "delete" by just flipping the "visible" flag that you're passing to the `in` parameter of the toggle.

I'm not sure if you're saving the list in some store, but you don't need the `useEffect` to get the visual effect you're looking for. Just have your `handleDelete` method flip the "visible" flag and that should work.

Here's the code from the Material's Slider demo, just with extra boxes added, as a demo of what I mean:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-10m4u?file=/demo.js